# How to build an R package base on other package？

Tags: r, stringr, r-package

I am trying to build an R package. But now my function has used some function from package `stringr`. Could anyone tell me how can I add `stringr` in to my package? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have used should be added to roxygen documentation. For example, if you used the function `stringr::str_extract()`, you can add-

```
#' @importFrom stringr str_extract()
```

And then run `roxygen2::roxygenise()` and you should see this function added to your `NAMESPACE` file. You can read about this in Hadley Wickham's (freely available book on how to make R packages): r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Or see this playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLk3B5c8iCV-T4LM0mwEyWIunIunLyEjqM

Comment: thank you @indrajeet Patil.